# How can I import a schema from mysql 5 to mysql 8

Tags: mysql, import, schema, upgrade

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 with a virgin installation while backing up my files. I have the /var/lib/mysql files in a backup from mysql 5. Those files include the schema I wish to use in the new Ubuntu 20.04, mysql 8 installation. I have the mysql 8 up and running, but could not figure out how to recover/import my schema from mysql 5.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a trivial answer, and it only applies if you still have access to mysql 5 on the old distro. Fortunately, I was able to boot into my old distro. Now the trivial SOLUTION:

```
`mysqldump -u foo -p SchemaName2bPreserved > mysql_backup`
```

You can give any other name you want to the dump file, then use the 'mysql_backup' file in your new distro with command
`mysql -u foo -p < mysql_backup`
Now I use the `mysqldump` command whenever I do a back up of my system.